# Latex, hyperlink, box size

Tags: hyperlink

How can the bluish color box for hyperlink be reduced in size to better fit line height?

Comment: Could you please show your code?
My color box fits nearly pefectly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VKKJ.png

Answer (score 4):

The `hyperlink` box will be the height of the line that it is on. You can put the link within a `\mbox{}` to minimize the height:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\GoogleLink}{\href{http://www.google.com}{Google}}

\begin{document}

\GoogleLink \quad
\mbox{\GoogleLink}\quad
$\dfrac{1}{2}$

\end{document}
```